# How can I encode data to JSON using Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm a haskell beginner. In Python, I can do this:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {'name': 'Jono', 'age': 36, 'skill': 'beginner'}
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"name": "Jono", "age": 36, "skill": "beginner"}'
```

So I'm trying to do the same thing in Haskell. Here's what I've tried:

```
*Main Data.Aeson> myData = [("name", "Jono"), ("age", "36"), ("skill", "beginner")]
*Main Data.Aeson> toJSON myData
Array [Array [String "name",String "Jono"],Array [String "age",String "36"],Array [String "skill",String "beginner"]]
*Main Data.Aeson> encode $ toJSON myData
"[[\"name\",\"Jono\"],[\"age\",\"36\"],[\"skill\",\"beginner\"]]"
```

I can't quite get it to output JSON. How can I do that? I've looked at the Data.Aeson documentation on Hackage, but I can't make heads or tails of it.

Comment: You are using a dictionary in python, but a list of tuples in Haskell. Use a dictionary (called "Map" in Haskell) instead

Answer (score 10):

Python frequently uses hashmaps as a lightweight data structure. In Haskell, data types are lightweight enough that it is idiomatic to just make one whenever you need to instead.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.TH

data Person = Person
    { name :: String
    , age :: Int
    , skill :: String -- you should probably use a more structured type here
    }

deriveJSON defaultOptions ''Person
```

Then you can use it. No need to call `toJSON` first.

```
> encode Person { name = "Jono", age = 36, skill = "beginner" }
"{\"name\":\"Jono\",\"age\":36,\"skill\":\"beginner\"}"
```

(Don't be fooled by the extra escaping and quote marks: this is just how the repl displays string-y things to avoid ambiguity. The `ByteString` being displayed is indeed a valid JSON object.)

This is almost identical to the example [given at the beginning of the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.4.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html); I encourage you to read that page, as there's lots of good information there.

Comment: Instead of explaining why the repl escapes things, why not simply write `putStrLn $ encode Person {...}` so that the escaping is not an issue?

Comment: @amalloy Hiding the issue does not make the issue disappear. It just makes it more confusing when the issue that is still there rears its head again. Explaining the issue, on the other hand, is a general solution. (Or, to say it another way: why try to trick the new programmer with `putStrLn $ encode Person { ... }`? Why not simply explain what the programmer sees and what it means, so that they do not need to memorize any tricks?)

Comment: the hackage man page indicates use of `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import GHC.Generics` — is that required these days? (was written in 2011)

Answer (score 9):

As @felk said, use a map:

```
Prelude> import Data.Aeson
Prelude Data.Aeson> import Data.Map
Prelude Data.Aeson Data.Map> myData = fromList [("name", "Jono"), ("age", "36"), ("skill", "beginner")]
Prelude Data.Aeson Data.Map> encode $ toJSON myData
"{\"age\":\"36\",\"name\":\"Jono\",\"skill\":\"beginner\"}"
...> Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8.putStrLn $ encode $ toJSON myData
{"age":"36","name":"Jono","skill":"beginner"}
```